Flutter still using older java after update. MacOS apple silicon
I have been trying to update my android SDK to latest for play store requirements. But since I updated the sdk flutter won't compile anymore
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0-rc3)
• Android SDK at /Users/shababhaidersiddique/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0-rc3
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
✗ Android license status unknown.
  Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
  See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

I cannot sign the android licenses because its using OpenJDK runtime build 11
$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
This tool requires JDK 17 or later. Your version was detected as 11.0.10.
To override this check, set SKIP_JDK_VERSION_CHECK.
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run
(/Users/shababhaidersiddique/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager): "exited code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions.

Even though I have openjdk22
$ java --version                   

openjdk 22.0.2 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 22.0.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 22.0.2, mixed mode, sharing)
I have re installed openjdk with
brew reinstall openjdk

many times and followed the provided hints to add symlink,PATH and CPPFLAGS
I don't know why flutter still finding java11 runtime. Would really appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance

I think you need to update the embedded java version in Android Studio: Android Studio -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deploy -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK -> Choose/add/download JDK

Thanks, I have just set grades to use latest. But flutter doctor still shows the embedded JDK 11. Is there a way to update embedded idk?

No matter what i tried flutter always use the embedded JDK. So the solution was to remove android studio and install the latest version which came bundled with latest jdk.

use this command:flutter config --jdk-dir your_jdk_path

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
